# When sql transaction auto commit off, can I get the primary key id?

Tags: java

Well, I have a customer profile with contact numbers. Say, User A has 2 mobile phones. If I set `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` at my Java end, and there will be 2 stored procedures to run this transactions: (1) add profile & (2) loop to add mobile phones. How do I get the CustomerId before it has set to commit? Will this be potential problem to data consistency when there will be a new CustomerId commit in the middle?

**tbl_customer**

```
CustomerId (PK, NOT NULL, UNIQUE, AUTO_INCREMENT)
CustomerName
Address
(etc)
```

**tbl_contact**

```
ContactId (PK, NOT NULL, UNIQUE, AUTO_INCREMENT)
CustomerId (FK REFERENCES tbl_customer(CustomerId), CONSTRAINT)
ContactType
ContactNumber
```

Comment: This depends on the database and the JDBC driver used. There's no generic answer.

Comment: As @LuiggiMendoza indicates, this depends on your database/use of stored procs/JDBC driver etc etc. However, _generally_ speaking, the next_id is generated and locked, when the insert to customer occurs. **Within the same transaction** the new CusomterId should be available  if it is setup as a foreign key reference in the contact table.